# Loop assignment count entries

Tags: loops

I have an assignment where I am supposed to take grades entered and output the amount of each grade and the percentage of that grade. The loop should stop when a negative number is entered. I think I have it now but I can't get it to compile.

```js
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Homework6_Project1  
{

    public static void main (String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner Keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        double count = Keyboard.nextDouble();
        gradecounter:
        do
        {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
        System.out.println("Enter the grade:");
        int Grade = Keyboard.nextInt();
    }
        if  (Grade >=90)
        {
            int CountA = 0;
            int A = Grade;
            double AverageA = A/count;
            ++CountA;
        }
        if (Grade<89 && Grade>=80)
        {
            int CountB = 0;
            int B = Grade;
            double AverageB = B/count;
            ++CountB;
    }
        if (Grade < 80 && Grade >=70)
        {
            int CountC = 0;
            int C = Grade;
            double AverageC = C/count;
            ++CountC;
        }
        if (Grade < 70 && Grade >= 60)
        {
            int CountD = 0;
            int D = Grade;
            double AverageD = D/count;
            ++CountD;
        }
        if (Grade < 60 && Grade >= 0)
        {
            int CountF = 0;
            int F = Grade;
            double AverageF = F/count;
            ++CountF;
        }
        while (Grade < 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Count of A grade's:" + " " + CountA + " Percentage of A's:" + " " + AverageA);
            System.out.println("Count of B grade's:" + " " + CountB + " Percentage of B's:" + " " + AverageB);
            System.out.println("Count of C grade's:" + " " + CountC + " Percentage of C's:" + " " + AverageC);
            System.out.println("Count of D grade's:" + " " + CountD + " Percentage of D's:" + " " + AverageD);
            System.out.println("Count of F grade's:" + " " + CountF + " Percentage of F's:" + " " + AverageF);
            break gradecounter;
    }
}
}
}
```

Comment: change `while` into `if`: `if` next `Grade` enetered is in some range then increment correspondent counter (`A`..`F`). Change counter type to `double` otherwise you'll have an *integer division* problem: `3 / 4 == 0` when `3.0 / 4 == 0.75`

Comment: This is a good attempt but I would look deeper at the logic of your code. You are setting your count variables to 0 just before you are working with them inside of your main loop. This makes it reset to 0 on each loop and increment to 1 pretty much immediately so your counters will always return 1. Aside from that is your complete misuse of the while loop. I'm not sure whether this made sense in your mind or you were hoping for a miracle but you need to figure out how to properly use the (do) while loop in order to fix your major issue. Also re-check your logic for test case 89. Good luck!